# How to use "this" with a bunch of eventlisteners?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to use "this" keyword when using `getElementsByClassName` array method?

The code works well, I just don't know how could I solve the "???" part... So there is 16 "refsz" classes and I would like to store the current refsz element (clicked element) and modify the content of its child.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("refsz");

for (var z = 0; z < elements.length; z++) {
    elements[z].addEventListener('click', Ref, false);
}


function Ref() {

???
this.find(.randomclass).innerText = "text";
???

}
```

Comment: The clicked element is exactly what `this` will refer to? There is no `???` necessary, your code works as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the event as parameter to the function, then, on `event.target` you'll get the clicked element:

```js
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("refsz");
    
    for (var z = 0; z < elements.length; z++) {
        elements[z].addEventListener('click', Ref, false);
    }
    
    function Ref(event) {
        event.target.innerText = "Text changed";
        // this.find(.randomclass).innerText = "text";
    }
```

```html
<div class="refsz">One</div>
<div class="refsz">Two</div>
<div class="refsz">Three</div>
<div class="refsz">Four</div>
<div class="refsz">Five</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect solution! :-))

Answer (score 0):

```
const Ref =(e) => e.target.innerText = 'text';
```

This might help... if that's what you want, it updates the element with the clicked class. else kindly explain further.